# Retrieving a TYPE_USE annotation declared when creating an Object, using reflection, in Java

Tags: java

Using Java 8, if I have this [TYPE_USE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE_USE) annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

And I use it like so:

```
MyObject obj = new @MyAnnotation("test") MyObject();
```

Using reflection, how can I access the annotation at runtime, from the `obj` instance?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could do this; where would the annotation get stored?  Objects don't carry around a list of their own personal annotations.  You could look at the annotations on public fields, but probably not on individual objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the [specification](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-architect-annotations-2177655.html), you can read that you will need to have **custom compiler plug-ins to process them**:

So, as described in [JSR 308 Explained: Java Type Annotations](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-architect-annotations-2177655.html) (Oracle) article (@see the Processing Type Annotations chapter), you must either write your own plugin, or you can give a try to the Checker Framework.

You can find an (in theory) uptodate Javadoc to the mentioned JSR 269 [here](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/pluggable_annotation_processing-1_9-mrel3-spec/index.html).

I found a tutorial [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-se-annotation-processing-api/annotation-processing-concepts.html) about how to write this custom plugin, you will need a similar class like this one:

```
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({com.example.MyAnnotation.class})
public class MyAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                                        RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        //processing logic here

        //returning false means other registered processor can still
        //continue processing
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you will need to create an SPI file and have to be packaged to jar, so it is not an easy process to get it work.

Maybe the usage of the Checker Framework is less complicated, if there is an already written plugin that fits your need.